# dispatchEvent Causes error failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular2 + TypeScript and when I try execute this code:

```
var event = new Event('check');
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This code causing the next error:

> failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.

I have tried everything, and found out that this will work:

```
var event = new CustomEvent('check');
```

Problem is that CustomEvent is not supported by any IE.

Another thing that works is:

```
var event = new Event('CustomEvent');
event.initCustomEvent('check');
```

Problem is that InitCustomEvent is deprecated.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this type error? Maybe make an exception somewhere in typescript? Or use any code that is not deprecated and works for IE Edge?

Answer (score 14):

Found a solution.

For some TypeScript settings, new Event **is** type of 'Event' only when we insert the second parameter, as this example:

```js
window.addEventListener('check', e => console.log(e.type))

var event = new Event('check', { bubbles: true, cancelable: false })
document.body.dispatchEvent(event) // event will buble up to window
```

Comment: pasting this into the chrome console I get the same error.

Comment: @Jacksonkr that is caused by the fact that we're dispatching `event` which hasn't been defined. The correct variable should have been `ev`

Answer (score 2):

I found another answer in StackOverFlow .

Link:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37687099/6264260

```
if (event && event.originalEvent) {
    var oe = event.originalEvent;
    this.dispatchEvent(new oe.constructor(oe.type, oe));
}
```

It works for me very well .