# Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

My test code emulates a test with the same line of code from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act):

```
button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true }));
```

But for some reason I'm getting this error from the same line of code:

```
Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.
```

Executable Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cache-xs3o2c

There is a button successfully grabbed by the test: `<button onClick={handleAdd} testid="handleAdd">Add</button>`

The test itself:

```
let container;

describe("Testing Buttons", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(container);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(container);
    container = null;
  });

  it("should increment", () => {
    act(() => {
      ReactDOM.createRoot(container).render(<App />);
    });

    let h1 = screen.getByRole("heading", { level: 1 });
    let count = Number(h1.innerHTML);
    expect(count).toBe(0);
    const button = screen.getByText("Add");
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
    act(() => {
      button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true }));
    }); // why bug?s literally the same as here: https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act
    expect(count).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

I've tried this code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920266/dispatchevent-causes-error-failed-to-execute-dispatchevent-on-eventtarget-p) but does not work for this case. Any ideas of fixes would be appreciated, thank you.